# Unable to install 32-bit Python with pyenv, despite appropriate flags set

Tags: python, openssl, python-2.6, pyenv

I'm looking to install the 2.6.6 Python as **32-bit** with **pyenv** on OS X, but get:

```
ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?
```

Despite having consulted [Common Build Problems](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems), and applying the flags suggested there, as well as installing Xcode developer tools, the problem persists. Here is the full command:

```
CFLAGS="-I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include -arch i386 -I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" LDFLAGS="-arch i386 -L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-arch=i386" pyenv install 2.6.6
```

... but this builds the 64-bit build, which is not what I need.

Oddly, the build works when just the following is tried:

```
CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" pyenv install 2.6.6
```

What are we missing? Does the following from the log imply that I need an openssl which was built for i386 / 32-bit?

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.dylib, file   
was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386):   
/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.dylibld: warning: 
ignoring file /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.dylib, file was built for 
x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): 
/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.dylib
```

Comment: The error message says exactly that. Why do you want the 32-bit version of Python?

Comment: Long story that is not pertinent, but if you must know, it's to allow for a very old wxPython that only works on 32-bit.

Comment: Try building the 32-bit version using these instructions: http://foodpicky.com/?p=99. The key appears to be using `darwin-i386-cc` when building.

Comment: OK. Would this achieve the same as what is suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4089574/1389110 ? And then, whatever method I use, how do I make sure that the pyenv build process uses the newly-built 32-bit install, rather than my *brew* install, which it seems to be currently doing?

Comment: Once you finish building, you will have a `python` binary somewhere in your build directory. You just need to point pyenv to that. And yes, those instructions look good.

Comment: So I built using Ned Deily's approach, resulting in in /tmp/openssl-1.0.0a. I then surmised that if I created the following symlink: `sudo ln -s /tmp/openssl-1.0.0a /usr/local/opt/openssl` then the build would pick up this 32-bit openssl, but it continues to warn about: `warning: ignoring file /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.dylib` so I guess something is amiss.

Comment: Replace `-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib"` with `-L/tmp/openssl-1.0.0a/lib"` Make sure that path exists first (`lib` may be in a deeper subdir).

Comment: Do it for `-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include` as well.