# pyenv not building with the openssl specified in CFLAGS, LFLAGS

Tags: python, macos, gcc, openssl, pyenv

With a 32-bit openssl bit on OS X (thanks to the suggestions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832512/unable-to-install-32-bit-python-with-pyenv-despite-appropriate-flags-set)), I kick off the **pyenv** build once again, this time setting the flags to point to where I've built the 32-bit openssl to (`/usr/local/ssl/`):

> CFLAGS="-I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include -arch i386
>   -I/usr/local/ssl/include" LDFLAGS="-arch i386 -L/usr/local/ssl/lib" CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-arch=i386" pyenv install 2.6.6

The build fails again, again complaining that files in the `/usr/local/opt/openssl/` are not 32-bit.

Why is the build still using the 64-bit openssl in `/usr/local/opt/openssl/`?

Comment: Is your `$PATH` set or symlinked to the other OpenSSL?

Comment: No, looks OK (I think): http://pastebin.com/S6gdvUMD

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but you could try adding `--with-openssl-dir=...` to `CONFIGURE_OPTS`.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, yes. I get 'configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-openssl-dir, --with-arch' though, and the build still fails. Does this look ok to you: http://pastebin.com/3Ab5Ev4b

Comment: You have two `==` (there should only be one), and remove the trailing `/`

Comment: Well-spotted. Still same issue though. It's also complaining about `--with-arch`, which surprises me, given that this is what is prescribed in the much-used **pyenv**'s documentation: https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems#installing-a-32-bit-python-on-64-bit-mac-os-x-this-will-not-work-on-linux

Comment: It might need to be `PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/ssl"` and remove it from `CONFIGURE_OPTS` (still might be wishful thinking, as it's normally used in `rbenv`)

Comment: One other thing you might try is `which openssl`, then `openssl version` to find out default path, version, etc.. Sometimes build options simply get ignored for whatever reason (usually because they assume using the newer library is always preferred) and you need to fix it another way.

Comment: Did u find a solution to this? I am still having this problem.