# configure flags/options to build 32 bit python on mac (OS X)

Tags: python, macos, build, configure, 32-bit

Python is embedded in an app that comes in 32 bit and 64 bit flavours.  I need both to release my code and I need to build from source for debugging.
I tried the only configure variable that seemed 32-bit specific (--with-universal-archs=32-bit) but that didn't seem to add any flags to gcc. eg:

```
 gcc -c -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -I. -I./Include -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Programs/python.o ./Programs/python.c
```

Answer (score 0):

from [How do I build OpenSSL as 32-bit (i386) on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084210/how-do-i-build-openssl-as-32-bit-i386-on-mac-os-x)

```
$ export CFLAGS="-arch i386"
$ export LDFLAGS="-arch i386"
$ ./configure
$ make
```